# Using lookup table for class method calls in python

Tags: python

having a class

```py
class MyClass:
    def func_a(self):
        """do a"""

    def func_b(self):
        """do b"""
```

and a mapping

```py
mapping = {
    "A": lambda: Myclass.do_a,
    "B": lambda: Myclass.do_b
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```py
thing = Myclass()

for i in ["A", "B"]:
    # call things appropriate method
```

So in the case of ["A", "B"] first call func_a on thing, and then func_b. How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: try `mapping[i].(thing)`, why does `func_a` not have a `self`

Comment: This is a very strange setup. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks @rioV87! Just added the self parameters.

Comment: Otherwise I would have 20 branches of if...else...

Comment: have you tried it? what is the question?

Comment: @rioV8: And what if the methods have parameters?

Comment: The question is how to do that

Comment: what is the point of the mapping and the lambdas? why not just `for method in [Myclass.do_a, Myclass.do_b]` ?

Comment: You don't need the mapping at all: just use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr): `for i in ['func_a', 'func_b']: getattr(thing, i)()`.

Comment: I need the mapping for other reasons.

Comment: In that case, store the method name in the mapping and do `getattr(thing, [mapping[i]])()`. This has the potential benefit of decoupling the mapping from the class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `lambda` for that

```
mapping = {
    "A": MyClass.func_a,
    "B": MyClass.func_b
}

thing = MyClass()

for i in ["A", "B"]:
    mapping[i](thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track! To achieve what you're looking for, you can use the mapping you provided to dynamically call the methods of your MyClass instance. However, you need to make a couple of adjustments to your mapping and function calls.

Here's how you can do it:

```js
class MyClass:
    def func_a(self):
        print("do a")

    def func_b(self):
        print("do b")

thing = MyClass()

mapping = {
    "A": lambda: thing.func_a(),
    "B": lambda: thing.func_b()
}

for i in ["A", "B"]:
    mapping[i]()  # Call the appropriate method based on the mapping
```

In this code, the lambda functions defined in the mapping call the corresponding methods on the thing instance of MyClass. The loop iterates over the list ["A", "B"], and for each item, it calls the corresponding lambda function, which in turn calls the appropriate method on the thing instance.